# При создании массива компилятор выдает ошибку cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
class TestArray{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int y=0;
            int ref;

            String [] island = new island[4];
            island[0]="Bermud";
            island[1]="Fidji";
            island[2]="Azov";
            island[3]="Kosumel";

            int[] index= new index[4];
            index[0]=1;
            index[1]=3;
            index[2]=0;
            index[3]=2;

            while(y<4){
                ref=index[y];
                System.out.print("Island");
                System.out.println(island[ref]);
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    TestArray.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                    String [] island = new island[4];
                                           ^
      symbol:   class island
      location: class TestArray
    TestArray.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                    index= new index[4];
                               ^
      symbol:   class index
      location: class TestArray
```

Comment: не понятно, что ты пытаешься сделать в этих строках:String [] island = new island[4]; int[] index= new index[4];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String [] island = new String[4];
...
int[] index = new int[4];
```

Comment: спасибо большое:)

Comment: @bazmexes Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Массив инициализируется не именем, а типом. Имя вы уже указали ранее.

```java
String (тип) [] island (имя) = new String[4]; (new означает создание нового объекта, String означает, что будет создан массив, содержащий объекты типа String)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь:)